# Excel VBScript not activating ECC 6.0 WIndow

Tags: sap-erp, sap-gui

Enclosed script is pre-recorded within ECC 6.0 (newer version of SAP) with minor modification. The script run fine, however, when it is copied into excel VBA, the macro doesn't call the ECC 6.0 window. Can anyone help what's missing?

```
Sub Test()      

If Not IsObject(SAPGuiApp) Then    
Set SAPGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")    
Set SAPGuiApp = SAPGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine    
End If    
If Not IsObject(Connection) Then    
Set Connection = SAPGuiApp.Children(0)    
End If    
If Not IsObject(session) Then    
Set session = Connection.Children(0)    
End If    
If IsObject(WScript) Then    
WScript.ConnectObject session, "on"    
WScript.ConnectObject SAPGuiApp, "on"    
End If    

session.findById("wnd[0]").resizeWorkingPane 134, 23, False    
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/n/sapapo/mdo4"    
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0 

End Sub
```